# How to write a Haskell QuickCheck generator for a Data.MeldableHeap priority queue

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

As a learning exercise I want to write a generator of `Data.MeldableHeap`.  I patterned it after:

https://gitorious.org/aocapq/aocapq/source/7f24bb1571b3bd89ada668ea81c37ccdeb825498:src/PriorityQueue/QuickCheck.hs   :

```
genericArbitrary :: (PriorityQueue pq, Arbitrary a, Ord a) => Gen (pq a)
genericArbitrary = fromList `fmap` listOf arbitrary
```

My code :

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Test.QuickCheck
import Control.Monad (liftM)
import Data.MeldableHeap

genericArbitrary :: (PQ pq, Arbitrary a, Ord a) => Gen (pq a)
genericArbitrary = liftM (foldr (\x acc -> insert x acc) empty) (listOf arbitrary)
```

but this above gets:

```
`pq' is applied to too many type arguments
In the type signature for `genericArbitrary':
  genericArbitrary :: (PQ pq, Arbitrary a, Ord a) => Gen (pq a)
```

Please provide guidance.

**Update** : with your help I got it:

https://github.com/haroldcarr/learn-haskell-coq-ml-etc/blob/master/haskell/course/coursera-fp-odersky-but-in-haskell/FRP01QuickCheck.hs

The actual tests could be better, but the point was to learn to use QuickCheck on a non-trivial example.   Thanks, H

Comment: It seems `PQ` is a type synonym for `BootWrap Integer`, not a typeclass.  Have you tried `(Arbitrary a, Ord a) => Gen (PQ a)`?

Comment: FYI, I was looking at the documentation here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/meldable-heap-2.0.3/docs/Data-MeldableHeap.html

Comment: ahh - typeclass, I get it (now hopefully I can do it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in the code you where looking at, they have a typeclass

```
class PriorityQueue pq where
  insert ...
```

With a bunch of operations for different priority queues. However, you don't have a typeclass. You have a datatype `PQ` which is a concrete type representing one implementation of a priority queue, namely a meldable heap.

Try instead

```
pqArbitrary :: (Arbitrary a, Ord a) => Gen (PQ a)
pqArbitrary = liftM (foldr (\x acc -> insert x acc) empty) (listOf arbitrary)
pqArbitrary' = foldr insert empty `fmap` listOf arbitrary
```

Also, I have to comment on the irony of testing one of the handful of packages on Hackage that's proven correct :) (meldable-heap is verified with coq)

Comment: Irony noted! ;-)   I just finished the Coursera Scala functional programming course where I did the exercises in both Scala and Haskell.  Now I am continuing in the followup functional reactive programming in Scala course and am trying to do everything in both Scala and Haskell too.   The first assignment is to use ScalaCheck on an already coded priority queue.  So I'm using QuickCheck for the first time with PQ as the subject.   Thanks.